Nav graph vs Fragment class navigation issue
We're using nav graph in our application.
As an requirement, we've a new Fragment class provided by some third party sdk. We wanted that fragment to use when it's accessible along with nav graph.
Will it be possible to handle?
While using fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.host_fragment, sdkFragment).commit()
it's attached to host_fragment layout, which causing issue. Note that app using navController.navigateTo(destinationgraph) is using what working expected and wants same experience if we can do with class sdkFragment.
Can someone please help if it's possible to do?
